# Submit Multiple Forms with jquery add onchange event for each value to fire php file

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, onchange

I have some code which works fine. The jquery script submits all the data from the html forms when clicking the submit link. By clicking the submit button the forms reduce themselves to what was selected and underneath the forms the products for this filtering event show up.
I want to add an onchange function to every input value to show the result of this filtering in advance. The result should appear in the result div and should be updated live when changing the checkbox value. 
How do i achieve this?
I need help to create the jquery function which collects the clicked checkboxes.

Here is the code.
http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gc4t-grw3

PHP

```
<?php 
$result = (isset($_POST)) ? $_POST : "";
foreach ($_POST as $key => $b) {
    if (is_array($b)){    
    $result = array_unique($b);
    $option_filter_help = implode(", ", $result); 
    }
}
print_r($result);
if (isset($_POST)){
   echo($option_filter_help);
   }
?>
```

Javascript

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function(event) {
        inputs = $(".myForm input");
        inputs.each(function(index) {
            $(inputs[index]).clone(true).appendTo("#submit-form").css("display", "none");
        });
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="results"></div>
<form action="" method="POST" class="myForm" onsubmit="return false;">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="optfilter[]" value="36" />36</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="optfilter[]" value="26" />26</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="optfilter[]" value="16" />16</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="optfilter[]" value="66" />66</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="optfilter[]" value="76" />76</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="optfilter[]" value="86" />86</label>
</form>
<form action="" method="POST" class="myForm" onsubmit="return false;">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="optfilter[]" value="136"/>136</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="optfilter[]" value="126"/>126</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="optfilter[]" value="116"/>116</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="optfilter[]" value="66" />66</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="optfilter[]" value="176"/>176</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="optfilter[]" value="86" />86</label>
</form> 
<form action="" method="POST" class="myForm" onsubmit="return false;">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="optfilter[]" value="236"/>236</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="optfilter[]" value="226"/>226</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="optfilter[]" value="216"/>216</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="optfilter[]" value="26"/>26</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="optfilter[]" value="276"/>276</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="optfilter[]" value="286"/>286</label>
</form>
<!-- Target form -->
<form action="" method="POST" id="submit-form">
<input type="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initiate event listener for checkbox change and append result data to the container.

**Example:**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
     var vals = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function(){
         return $(this).val();
     }).get();
     $('#results').text((vals.length ? vals.join(', ') : 'Nothing selected.'))
});
```